# A problem from Observations on Arithmetica

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, diophantine-equations, math-history

In his Observations on Diophantus' Arithmetica, Fermat writes the following (translated)

> In the natural progression starting at unity, the product of an arbitrary number times its immediate successor makes double the triangle of the first number.
>
> If the multiplier is the triangle of the number immediately following, we have three times the pyramid of the first number.
>
> If it is the pyramid of the number immediately following, we have the quadruple of the “triangulo-triangulaire” of the first number, and so on indefinitely, following a uniform
> and general rule.

**Question 1**

> What would this be in modern symbolic notation?

**Question 2**

> What would be a proof for the same?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "n-gon-numbers" ?

Comment: @Peter I got this from the translated version of Fermat's copy of Diophantus' Arithmetica. I think pyramid numbers are [these](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_n$ denote the $n$th triangular number, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n i$, and let $T^{(2)}_n$ denote the $n$th pyramidal number, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n T_i$. Then the first sentence says:

> $n(n+1)=2T_n$

This is simply the usual formula for $T_n$, which can be proved by induction. We usually write it:

$$T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}$$

The second sentence says:

> $nT_{n+1}=3T^{(2)}_n$

We can also show this by induction, using the previous formula. In notation more in line with modern sensibilities:

$$T^{(2)}_n = \frac{nT_{n+1}}{3} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}=\binom{n+2}{3}$$

The last one, I don't know a modern name for, but let's let $T^{(3)}_n=\sum_{i=1}^nT^{(2)}_i$. Fermat seems to be telling us that:

> $nT^{(2)}_{n+1}=4T^{(3)}_n$

We would write this today as:

$$T^{(3)}_n=\frac{nT^{(2)}_{n+1}}{4} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}=\binom{n+3}{4}$$

I'm sure we could prove this by induction, again using the above formula.

Finally, Fermat tells us that this pattern continues. In other words:

$$T^{(k)}_n=\frac{nT^{(k-1)}_{n+1}}{k+1} = \frac{(n+k)!}{(n-1)!(k+1)!}=\binom{n+k}{k+1}$$

I reckon this proof would be a double-induction.

Comment: If $n$ is a natural number, we can also write $$T_n^{(3)}=\binom{n+3}{4}$$

Comment: Or in general, $T^{(k)}_n=\binom{n+k}{k+1}$?

Comment: Now a combinatorial argument for the general formula would be really nice, making all that induction unnecessary!

Comment: When I want to choose a committee of $k+1$ people from a pool of $n+k$ indexed people, I can just pick in $\binom{n+k}{k+1}$ ways, or I can first select the member with the lowest index, and then select the remaining $k$ committee members from the people with higher index. That makes $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \binom{n+k-i}{k} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \binom{j + k-1}{k}$$ ways to choose, since the $n^{\text{th}}$ lowest index is the largest admissible choice for the member with lowest index.